# Multiple queries with MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm making a query using PHP/MySqli like this:

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM rooms
WHERE 1
LIMIT 0, 30 ");

$result = "['Number', 'Status', 'Category', 'Pbx Number', 'Price for today'],";
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($id, $number, $status, $category, $pbx);

while ($sql->fetch()) {

$result .= " ['$number', '$status', '$category', '$pbx',"  . priceForRoom($mysqli, $number, time()) . "],";

}

$sql->free_result();
return ($result);
```

It all works fine, as long as `priceForRoom()` doesn't need to connect to the mysqli db to return a value. But, as soon as I implement `priceForRoom()` and use mysqli I get this error:

```
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

So many people got the same error, but I still don't understand how can I fix this. I don't want to store the results in an array, how can I use `mysqli_store_result` without going procedural-style? I'd like to keep my code object oriented: where should I ask mysqli to store the result?

Comment: what is `priceForRoom()`?

Comment: 2 downvotes and no one who take the time to explain them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the results fetched to your variables before you can use them again.

Hence

```
$sql->bind_result($id, $number, $status, $category, $pbx);
while ($sql->fetch()) {
  $sql->store_result();
```

Read up more about [`store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) on php.net.

Comment: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::store_results()"

Comment: @Saturnix Oh, sorry. It is `store_result` and not `results`.